# Firefox radial gradient issue

Tags: firefox, css, gradient, radial-gradients

Trying to set radial gradient to the bg. The problem is, all other browsers shows gradient, on Firefox doesn't. What's wrong? Generated this code on this website http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (with ie9 support)

```
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(234,234,234,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=1 );
```

Comment: What version of FF do you have?

Comment: version 8.0. have you tested it?

Comment: tural.no-ip.org live page. please take a look. Maybe it's because of my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Because all elements within `body` are absolutely positioned, `body` has no height.

You've added `height: 100%` to `body`, but `html` also had no `height`, so `height: 100%` on `body` wasn't doing anything.

Adding `height: 100%` to `html` makes it as high as the viewport, so then `height: 100%` on `body` works.

Comment: the white amibient must be at centre of bg. But IE9 shows at left top corner

Comment: The reason for that is that the `filter` is also being applied. *Carefully* read the instructions on http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ ("IE9 Support (?)") . `"Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG).
Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->"`

Comment: Your gradient is very subtle, which makes it hard to tell the difference between the radial version and the `filter` version, at first glance. Consider making the gradient more obvious.